# Laravel, generate a new link automatically

Tags: laravel

I have created a laravel project, and it includes 4 different blog entries. I want each blog entry to create its own url using the blogs title, so for example /blog/{blog:id}, however I am unsure to do this.

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    $links = \App\Link::paginate(2);

    return view('welcome', ['links' => $links]);
});

Route::get('/{links:id}', function (Links $links) {
    return $links;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create links from your Blog title.

```
//Blog model
function getUrl(){
    return $this->title; //Blog title
}
```

This way you can generate links directly using Blog model instead of using the Link class.

Then when showing your Blog, you will have to do something like this to retrieve by blog title rather than blog id:

```
$blog = Blog:where('title', $request->title)->first();
```

This option might need tinkering though, since you might have Blogs with the same title. If you have the same title, you can also use the Blog id in the getUrl() in order to be able to find the correct Blog object.

Another option I would prefer better would be to use one of these packages, which helps you out with slugs:

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable

https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable